# Controller and Eloquent woes

Tags: laravel, laravel-4

I am new to Laravel and have been banging my head on this issue for a while. I am merely trying to get a single row from a table and hand it off to a view.

The table has two fields that should match up with this query, the first of course is the id and the second is user_id which matches the logged in user. When its done I plan on responding with a failure message (no record found that matches id: X).

```
public function show($id)
{
   $data = Partners::where('id', $id);->where('user_id', Auth::user()->id)->get();
   return View::make('partners.showone')
            ->with('data', $data)
            ->with('title', 'View Record')
            ->with('breadcrumb', 'View Partner');       

}
```

In my view:

```
{{ $data->firstName }}
```

This configuration gives me an error of:

Undefined property: Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder::$firstName

Comment: Is this a typo? `);->where(`. If you var_dump($data) what do you get?

Comment: Well... when I did not have the typo in it, I got a large multidimensional array... but I could never get the value to output into the view.. with the typo... It retrieved Eloquent code (a very large return).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Typo...you have a ; in the middle there....it should be....

```
   $data = Partners::where('id', $id)->where('user_id', Auth::user()->id)->get();
```

but your query really should be this..

```
$data = Partners::find($id)->where('user_id', Auth::user()->id)->first();
```

if you just want one row

**EDIT (based on your comments below)**

For your phones in your Partner model (Im working with Laravel 3 btw)

```
function phone(){
 return $this->hasMany('Phone');
}
```

Then with the above $data query, you can get the phone by...

```
$data->phone();
```

Comment: Ok, typo aside, I think I missed the ->first() as its a one to one relationship right?

Comment: So, if I wanted to pull from another model say, Phones (a hasMany relationship), I would need to build another array (like $phones) then add that with with->('phones', $phones) or right?

Thanks for helping me make sense of Laravel.

Comment: no, the first() just pulls one row, as opposed to multiple rows, it has nothing to do with one to one

Comment: Im not sure I understand what you're asking above here with the Phones, I edited my answer, if thats not what you want let me know

Comment: I think I follow.. I have another table called phone_numbers which has a user_id foreign_key tied to id in the partners table. I would like to get an array of all phone numbers assigned to that partner in the most efficient manner.

Comment: Can I call data->phone() in the view? or do a  @foreach on it?

Comment: Yeah I believe so....if youve passed the $data to the view in the controller, then you should be able to